# Regularly loading a large file into python

Tags: python

So I have this large file (about 1.5GB) which I load into python pretty regularly. The loading parses it into an object, that ends up taking about 3GB of RAM.
The loading process is not that long (takes about 40 seconds on my PC), but still it becomes an issue when I want to debug programs that load it.

I was trying to come up with a solution for loading it more quickly, at first I though about pickling the resulting python object, but as I said earlier it's 3GB, so unpickling it ended up taking even longer then the parsing process.

Is there a way to let python access it more quickly? I am not really opposed to any working solution (cloud server? other programming languages?) but I am not even sure if this is technically possible at all.

Comment: What is the file's type ?

Comment: its .RRF, but the reading process treats it like a text file, the resulting object is basically a dictionary but with some added methods and the values are another custom object

Comment: Reading a 2.4GB text file line by line (and doing nothing on the lines) takes around 8 seconds on my PC. So you should probably check if there's room for optimization in the processing of the data

Comment: It takes time because I do more than just read it. The simple call to "file.read()" does not take much time itself.
The part that takes a bit more time is building the actual object out of it which includes parsing each line (just over 10m lines) to an object that I can extract relevant info from, and sort these lines into the main object's internal dictionary in a way that makes sense.
I don't think there is much fat in the way I do this (and 40 seconds for that feels OK), but since that whole thing is static I feel that there must be a way to make it persist somehow.

Comment: I have tried using pickle to serialize the final object to a file, the resulting file weighs 3.5gb. I used timeit to see how long it takes to load it from the pickle, and it takes 50-70 seconds which is considerably longer than just parsing the original file (which takes about 40 seconds)

Comment: are u using pickle or cPickle ? if not cPickle try cPickle see it help a bit, my experience with pickle was pretty fast but didn't deal with up to GB large pickle

Comment: if pickle doesn't works, u could try explorer HDF5 format with h5py, pickle seems not really great to deal with too large dataset